# Indexing in a list of dictionaries affects all the dictionaries

Tags: python, list, dictionary, indexing

I made a list of dictionaries as below.

```
num=5
core_dict ={'c1':[0]*num , 'c2':[0]*num}
link=[core_dict]*3
```

this gives the (correct) output:

```
[ {'c1': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 'c2': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]},  #represents link1 for me
  {'c1': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 'c2': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]},  #represents link2 for me
  {'c1': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 'c2': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]}]  #represents link3 for me
```

Then I want to replace the `'c1'` values of link2. I do:

```
link[1]['c1']=[10]*num
```

but this changes the values for the `'c1'` key for every dictionary in the list. **How can I do indexing to only affect one dictionary?**

```
[ {'c1': [10, 10, 10, 10, 10], 'c2': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]},  #represents link1 for me
  {'c1': [10, 10, 10, 10, 10], 'c2': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]},  #represents link2 for me
  {'c1': [10, 10, 10, 10, 10], 'c2': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]}]  #represents link3 for me
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your initialization of `link` points every element to the same dictionary (i.e. the same location in memory):

Instead of using:

```py
link=[core_dict]*3
```

use

```py
from copy import deepcopy
link=[deepcopy(core_dict) for _ in range(3)]
```

so that the memory used by each dictionary is completely separate.

Comment: I wish I could upvote this multiple times!  I struggled with this for so many hours. First, not knowing where in my big code this mistake is happening, and then not knowing why this thing happens when logically the indexing was looking fine to me. But you mean if I did not have that `link` line then was my way of indexing correct?

Comment: Ok, I get it. Sorry, It is `link` in both places, Not `link` once and then `link_core_slots`. I edited it now.  I have accepted your ans. I had upvoted and hurriedly went to correct my code. My hundreds of lines of code is working now!.

Comment: If they're the same, then the indexing should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

You could also create `link` like this without importing `deepcopy`:

```
link=[core_dict.copy() for i in range(3)]
```

Comment: this works too.

Comment: This won't work if you ever need to call `.append()` or extend on any of the lists in the dictionary, because the memory for those lists remains shared if you don't use `deepcopy`.

Comment: @BrokenBenchmark ok, I didn't know about these possible after-effects.